# code in vb from C#; adding a property

Tags: vb.net, properties, delegates

how would I write the next code in vb:

```
 this.axMap1.PreviewKeyDown += delegate(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.KeyCode)
     {
         case Keys.Left:
         case Keys.Right:
         case Keys.Up:
         case Keys.Down:
             e.IsInputKey = true;
             return;
     }
 };
```

and what is a form constructor in vb?
I am a novice, pls be patient:)

Thanks in advance,
Asher

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code translation service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddHandler Me.axMap1.PreviewkeyDown, AddressOf Sub(sender, e)
                                                   Select Case e.KeyCode
                                                       Case Keys.Left Or
                                                            Keys.Right Or
                                                            Keys.Up Or
                                                            Keys.Down
                                                           e.IsInputKey = true
                                                   End Select
                                               End Sub
```

Did you tried to google about "Form constructor"?
This link was first in the search result [MSDN Form Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.form(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Hi Fabio,Thanks. I did look at that link but it is not how the code looks when you open a new form project in visual studio. I will keep on learning